# Como implementar correctamente GET POST PUT de una API REST desde FLUTTER

Tags: api, flutter, http-post, http-get

queria hacer una consulta tengo una Api que hace GET POST Y PUT. Mi pregunta, en flutter:

1. Debo siempre llamarlos como un FUTURE a mis metodos que hacen GET o POST o PUT yo los he probado sin ponerlos y funciona "Normal".
2. Tambien vi que algunos recomiendan usar FUTURE conjuntamente con FUTURE BUILDER para crear los widgets. He probado sin usar ninguno de los 2 y funciona "Normal".
3. Como deberia trabajar este escenario donde combino update y read a mi base de datos desde mi API. Yo lo he estado haciendo asi LEO MI URL CON LOS DATOS y los muestro en mi pantalla luego con un boton llamo al metodo de mi API que consulta los estados de esos registros (esos estados lo consigo de otra API externa) y dentro de este metodo que lee los estados llamo al metodo que hace el UPDATE para actualizar esos estados obtenidos en mi base de datos y dentro de este mismo metodo llamo a mi al primer metodo que me mostraba los documentos(el que uso inicialmente para mostrarlos en el movil) pero ya con los "estados actualizados". El Detalle que me devuelve con los estados antiguos a veces me devuelve algunos por ejemplo eran 20 y solo me muestra 5 (los otros 15 ya se actualizo su estado actual), con lo que podria concluir que mi metodo de consulta se realiza antes que acabe de actualizar los estados. ¿Como puedo controlar eso?.

Espero algun comentario o ayuda de como trabajar correctamente en esos puntos muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. El Future se utiliza cuando en un método se desconoce cuanto va a demorar en ejecutarse por lo cual se debe poner un await para asegurarse de que este se ejecute completamente.
   En esta situación de hacer llamadas a api es muy recomendable utilizar Future ya que la velocidad de internet varia para cada usuario y quieres asegurarte de que los datos siempre lleguen completos.

Ejemplo:

```
 Future<Report> getIncidenceReportById(int id) async {
    final incidenceStatus = await _httpService
        .getHttp("${ApiResources.bossDetailOfIncidence}/$id/incidence-report") as String;

    final decodedIncidenceStatus = jsonDecode(incidenceStatus) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Report.fromJson(decodedIncidenceStatus);;
}
```

2. En la situación de utilizar FutureBuilder, diria que depende del proyecto (widget, view) que se vaya a crear, puedes omitir utilizar el FutureBuilder, pero a cambio tendras que tener una buena gestión de estados. Necesitaras:

   - Tus llamadas a la api con Future y await.
   - Convertir la respuesta en un modelo que vayas a utilizar.
   - Revisar que no ocurra un error entre medio.
   - Dependiendo de lo anterior mostrar si ocurrio un error o no.
   - Mostrar que la pantalla esta cargando mientras se realiza todo lo anterior.
   - Si todo bien utilizar tu modelo para mostrar información en pantalla.
3. No llego a entender muy bien lo que mencionaste en este punto, pero lo que puedo decir es que puede suceder si es que no estas utilizando Future y await. Lo que deberias hacer es llamar a tu primera API, utilizar await y realizar la segunda llamada, igualmente con un await y asi la aplicación, espera hasta que la información este completa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta ya me quedo un poco claro los puntos 1 y 2. Con respecto al punto 3 a ambos le pongo el await en una sola pantalla muestro mis documentos con un estado 1 (los jalo de mi BD) y luego realizo un update por decir con el estado 2. En teoria el update (si tiene el await) termina su trabajo y lo que hago es volver a jalar mis documentos, si tenia 10 con estado 1 y si vuelvo hacer la misma consulta con los mismos parametros deberia estar limpia la pantalla.

Comment: Pero me muestra como si no hubiese hecho el update (Miro mi BD y ya tiene el estado 2). Por eso concluyo que mi consulta se ejecuta mas rapido que mi update.